# Fuctional equation similar to 2022 Putnam Exam B6

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Are there any continuous functions $$f \colon \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$$ (notation indicating strictly positive reals) that satisfy the functional equation:

$$f(xf(y))f(yf(x))=f(x+y)$$

for all $x, y$, other than $f(x) = 1$?

(Number sense tells me that it is conceivable there is a nonincreasing function on $[0,\infty)$ with f(0)=1 that when restricted to $\mathbb{R}^+$ could satisfy this equation. But I'd guess such an example would need to be more complicated than the simple rational functions in the solution to Putnam 2022 B6.

Trying the same method as the solution of B6 given here:

https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2022s.pdf

and to make things easier, assuming that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)$$ exists and that we are looking for a non-increasing function, it seems to me that the arguments can be modified to show that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$. But the argument becomes IMO unfixably broken at Equation (7), since it becomes $$f(xf(x)) = \sqrt{f(2x)}$$, and we cannot say that this latter is bounded away from 0 like the 1/2 in Equation (7).)

Comment: $f(x) = 0$ works as well.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  What happens if you try to use the same methods that work for the similar problem?

Comment: I'm guessing $\mathbb{R}^+$ here is $(0, \infty)$, due to what you're saying in parentheses? That notation is ambiguous as it can also designate $[0,\infty)$, just a heads up.

Comment: Given that $f(xf(y))f(yf(x))=f(x+y)$ and that $f$ has fourth derivatives, then $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.